# Sort Batch File Results

Tags: sorting, batch-file

I have the following within a batch file.

```
for /D %%A IN (*) DO echo %%A>> output.txt
```

I want the results from this to be alphabetically, instead it appears to be ordering by date.

Can anyone suggest how this could be achieved?

Comment: Interesting. In my system, `FOR /D` (as well as simply `FOR`) seems to return items in alphabetical order. When I need a different one, I have to employ something like in @rene's answer. If the sorting of items returned by `FOR`/`FOR /D` can be customised, it would be great to know how it is possible.

Comment: @AndriyM FOR returns items in filesystem order. For FAT this order is not specified, but approximates to creation order. For NTFS this is collation order, based on the collation of the computer that formatted the drive.

Comment: @Neil: Thanks. I take it you can't change the (default) order then.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the dir command to sort your folders and the echo them...

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ( 'dir /b /ad /oN') do echo %%a  >> output.txt
```

And if you only want to echo the directoryname

> dir /b /ad /oN >> output.txt

would be enough...

On the command prompt `help for` and  `help dir`  are quitte usefull...

Comment: Not sure if it is my system but this solution results in the folder names being cut off as soon as there is a space in the folder name.

Comment: You'd have to turn off the default `delims` to handle names with spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `sort` command.

```
for /D %%A IN (*) DO echo %%A>> output.txt
sort output.txt > sorted_output.txt
```

you can read more about this command by invoking `sort /?` or [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sort.mspx?mfr=true).

As you can read in the help of the command, you can use `/O` to redirect the output to a file instead of the standard output. And with that you can avoid the need of two files:

```
for /D %%A IN (*) DO echo %%A>> output.txt
sort output.txt /O output.txt
```

EDIT: a nice one-liner could be:

```
(for /D %%A IN (*) DO echo %%A) | sort > output.txt
```

It is also much faster since it writes the output once at the end.

Comment: This is a great solution, is there a way so that it doesnt create two files?

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer @rene's answer in this situation, but your answer was useful for me as a reminder about this great `sort` utility.